# How to set ubuntu to use specific graphic unit?

Tags: xorg, hybrid-graphics

I tried lots of thnigs but nothing changed.

I have lenovo y510p with dual nVidia GT750m graphic cards. With two graphic cards ubuntu doesn't boot normally.I tried to install and boot ubuntu with one grapchic card and it worked perfectly but i dont want to plug in and out every time i want to use ubuntu .

Is it possible to make an exeption to ubuntu to use only intel's graphic card?

Edit:I noticed that i dont have an xorg.conf file in /etc/X11 directory.So i made one by `X  -configure`.And when i put it in /etc/X11 screen freezes on boot but i can hear starting sound of ubuntu.Here is the xorg.conf file which makes my screen freeze http://pastebin.com/L1TSeX9k (i made this xorg.conf when just 1 video card plugged).

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't boot normally"? Any error logs, etc.?

Comment: This [post](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/572224/two-graphics-cards-in-linux-how-/) will help you.

Comment: Generally black screen when i tried two cards.I tried nomodeset and it boots only terminal.Then i logged in then typed startx it gives an error(no screen found).

Answer (score 0):

I don't use nvidia. I forced that grub always set i915 driver. Without this driver the brightness and dual monitor doesn't work. Try: 
[Lenovo y510p with HDMI monitor (RESOLVED)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/407009/lenovo-y510p-with-hdmi-monitor-resolved)