# Lenovo y510p with HDMI monitor (RESOLVED)

Tags: 13.10, xorg, multiple-monitors, live-usb, lenovo

When I boot from Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit live from USB, then secondary monitor on HDMI works fine. After installing Ubuntu, the secondary monitor on HDMI port doesn't work. If I reboot with live Ubuntu, then monitor works again.

Is it a bug? Is there a patch or a workaround?

Lenovo y510p notebook, Intel HD4600 VGA
lsmod after live boot: http://pastebin.com/977j4mzV
lsmod after install: http://pastebin.com/PdfCtjfj

**UPDATE:** `lshw -c video | grep configuration`

When I boot from Live USB: `configuration: driver=i915 latency=0` (dual monitor works)

When I boot from SSD: `configuration: latency=0`

Comment: What did you do to enable the monitor? Have you been to the displays menu and tried configuring it?

Comment: The secondary monitor doesn't show up in display menu from install, but I see it when I boot from live USB.

Comment: I made an update. I don't know why not shown "driver=i915" when I boot my SSD... but shown when boot from Live USB. lsmod shown that i915 has been loaded in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

Edit grub config:

```
sudo su
nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash i965.modeset=1"
```

Update grub:

```
update-grub
```

Reboot, and it works fine.